# Почему рендер узла в DOM дереве происходит только после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, dom, render

Реализованный функционал:

При выборе авто из select и клику по кнопке "Добавить", рендерится карточка с авто. Суть в свойстве объекта `Cruise`, если `Cruise === 1`, когда `checkbox === checked`, то в карточке рендерится данный узел:

```
carCruiseTxt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Круговой тариф"));
```

из функции `addCruiseToRenderCarCart`.

При `Cruise === 0`, соответственно узел "Круговой тариф" не будет рендерится в карточке авто. **Данный функционал отрабатывает!**

Так же я сделал фиктивный запрос с сервера в функции `fetchVehicleData`, с помощью которого, при клике по checkbox я получаю в панели "Тип транспорта" с сервера данные авто (которые сохранены у юзера в личном кабинете), которое юзер так же может отрендерить при клике по добавленным данным. При таком сценарии, с сервера в любом случае приходит `Cruise === 1`, и узел:

```
carCruiseTxt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Круговой тариф"));
```

должен рендерится в карточке, но на данный момент узел не рендерится при первом добавлении, а рендерится в карточке уже после перезагрузки страницы. Я как смог вытащил и склеил куски кода с 3 модулей, где происходят все операции и реализовал сценарий событий. Ссылки на песочницы:

https://jsfiddle.net/6z8hfu4a/19/

https://codepen.io/Andy41/pen/mdvwGbY?editors=1111

Из того что я понял, по какой то причине, если добавлять с помощью функции `getCarListAll` то код не находит `carCruiseContainer`, хотя в DOM дереве devtools, он присутствует.

---

**В двух словах нужно нажать на checkbox, а потом по добавленному тексту данных авто, что имеется на скриншоте:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Рендерится карточка с авто:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Та же карточка после перезагрузки страницы (Появился "Круговой тариф", хотя должен был появиться до перезагрузки страницы):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема то у Вас с чем конкретно? В коде у Вас каша из разметки и данных. Поставьте точки остановки (breakpoint) в консоли и выполните пошаговую отладку кода.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при рендере карточки авто не появляется надпись "Круговой тариф" в самой карточке, а после перезагрузки страницы появляется.

Comment: Что показала пошаговая отладка кода и что Вы понимаете под рендером?

Comment: В данный момент в функции addCruiseToRenderCarCart, не находит блок carCruiseContainer и мне кажется что ошибка где то тут: const carBlock = document.getElementById(car.ID);
           const carCruiseContainer = carBlock.querySelector(".car__cruise");

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена, оказывается вместо реализации данной функции: `addCruiseToRenderCarCart`,

можно всего лишь, в шаблоне функции `renderCars()` описать тернарник:

```
<div class="car__cruise">${car.Cruise === 1 ? 'круговой тариф' : ''}
```